# Asynctask (DownloadImageTask) failure

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-imageview, worker

If you know my last question, it was to do with 4 activities randomly crashing. This is a follow-up.

I tried implementing a worker thread as recommended to me, but the Asynctask code that I've put in isn't working. I've tried looking at Stack Overflow and the Android documentation to no avail. Is there a way to get this working?

Here's my code:

```
    package tk.test.wirewizard;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import tk.test.wirewizard.R;



    public class HDMI extends Activity {
    ImageView mImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_hdmi);

    Button b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    Button b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);


    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HDMI.this, Rcawire.class);
            HDMI.this.startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(HDMI.this, Start.class);
            HDMI.this.startActivity(i);

        }


    });


    new DownloadImageTask().execute("http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61Tchc9QyeL._SL290_.jpg");
}

private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> implements tk.test.wirewizard.DownloadImageTask {
    /**
     * The system calls this to perform work in a worker thread and
     * delivers it the parameters given to AsyncTask.execute()
     */
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        return loadImageFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    }

    private Bitmap loadImageFromNetwork(String url) {
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * The system calls this to perform work in the UI thread and delivers
     * the result from doInBackground()
     */
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        mImageView.setImageBitmap(result);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.hdmi, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

            return true;
        }

    }

}
```

Hopefully someone will be able to work this out.

Thanks!

Comment: "isn't working" doesn't tell us anything. Does it crash? does it not execute? does it paint the walls of your house green?

Comment: what's the error you are getting? can we see the logcat

Comment: @panini Sorry about that, should have been more specific. It does crash at this particular activity.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning null from your `doInBackground()` method and try to set this result as a `Bitmap` to your `ImageView`.

This will clearly throw a `NullPointerException`(because the result in `onPostExecute()` is, of course, null) and hence crashing your app.

Comment: Please tell me, how do I fix this?

Comment: @user3886014 return an actual `Bitmap` object from `doInBackground()` instead of null